# Does it make sense to detect keypoints with SIFT and describe them with SURF or ORB?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sift, surf

I'm working on a computer vision classification project and I'm trying different detectors and descriptors. I use opencv 3 and python and I saw that it is possible to locate keypoints with SIFT and describe them through SURF or ORB descriptors.
The same applies to other combinations of these 3.
When I say that it is possible to do so, I mean that the algorithm runs and descriptors are found (and even in large numbers). 
What I ask is, since all three are both detector and descriptor by default, does it make sense to combine them in this way?

Comment: depends on your task. But yes, it's by concept, that keypoints are independent from descriptors. BUT: Sometimes it is mote efficient to use the right combination, because they might share some precomputed data, like in SURF where both, detector and descriptor use the integral image! In the past (maybe still) many people use FAST keypoints with some descriptors.

Comment: Do what you want!

Comment: Thanks, yeah maybe it's better not to mix them, anyway I think I'll do some tests!